# How to create a specific type of menu?

Tags: android, menu, android-studio

I create this menu https://www.flickr.com/photos/128077707@N03/)

and want to use it on an android aplication, I have only create squares and circles imagebuttons and if the red type of menu options are placed on an imagebutton it would function as a square imagebutton. There is any way to use this button Menu style on an android application (the buttons have red background)? any links would be great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the exact match, but you can check-out following projects and try to change them according to your needs.

https://github.com/lemonlabs/ExpandableButtonMenu

https://github.com/onivas/MenuAnimation

That 2 links might be a starting point.

Regards,